# Подсветка результатов поиска или выделение слов запроса поиска в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-search-view

Как изменить цвет, или подсветить искомое слово  при использовании SearchView в отфильтрованном RecyclerView ?

**MainActivity**

```
public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    MyRecAdapter myRecAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Post> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.chapter1_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myrec);
        createdata();
        myRecAdapter = new MyRecAdapter(list, Chapter1.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Chapter1.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecAdapter);
    }


    void createdata() {

        list = new ArrayList<>();

        String topic_1_1 = getResources().getString(string.topic_1_1);
        String text_1_1 = getString(string.text_1_1);
        String topic_1_2 = getResources().getString(string.topic_1_2);
        String topic_1_3 = getResources().getString(string.topic_1_3);
        String text_1_3 = getString(string.text_1_3);

        list.add(new Post(topic_1_1, text_1_1));
        list.add(new Post(topic_1_2, ""));
        list.add(new Post(topic_1_3, text_1_3));


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


        final List<Post> filteredModelList = filter(list, newText);

        if (filteredModelList.size() > 0) {

            myRecAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Chapter1.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private List<Post> filter(List<Post> models, String query ) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();

        final List<Post> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Post model : models) {

            final String text = model.getPostTitle().toLowerCase();
            final String text_sub = model.getPostSubTitle().toLowerCase();

            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);

            }
            else {
                if (text_sub.contains(query)) {
                    filteredModelList.add(model);
                }

            }


        }
        createdata();
        myRecAdapter = new MyRecAdapter(filteredModelList, Chapter1.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Chapter1.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecAdapter);
        myRecAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return filteredModelList;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyRecAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecAdapter.VH> {
    public List<Post> parkingList;

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> mCountryModel;

    public MyRecAdapter(List<Post> parkingList, Context context) {
        this.parkingList = parkingList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyRecAdapter.VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyRecAdapter.VH(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mycardview, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecAdapter.VH holder, int position) {

            holder.t1.setText(Html.fromHtml(parkingList.get(position).getPostTitle()));
            holder.t2.setText(Html.fromHtml(parkingList.get(position).getPostSubTitle()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parkingList.size();
    }

    public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView t1, t2;

        public VH(View view) {
            super(view);

            t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            t2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);

        }

    }


    public void setFilter(List<Post> countryModels) {
        mCountryModel = new ArrayList<>();
        mCountryModel.addAll(countryModels);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

**Post**

```
public class Post {

    private String postTitle;
    private String postSubTitle;

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public void setPostTitle(String postTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
    }

    public String getPostSubTitle() {
        return postSubTitle;
    }

    public void setPostSubTitle (String postSubTitle) {
        this.postSubTitle = postSubTitle;
    }


    public Post(String postTitle, String postSubTitle) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.postSubTitle = postSubTitle;


    }
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен, создайте и прикрепите изображение того, какого результата вы хотите добиться

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `Spannable`

```
String displayName = contact.getFullName();
int startIndex = indexOfSearchQuery(displayName);
if (startIndex == -1) {
    holder.name.setText(displayName);
} else {
    SpannableString highlightedName = new SpannableString(displayName);
    highlightedName.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(context, R.style.searchTextHiglight), startIndex,
            startIndex + searchTerm.length(), 0);
    holder.name.setText(highlightedName);
}
```

Функция `indexOfSearchQuery`:

```
private int indexOfSearchQuery(String displayName) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchTerm)) {
        return displayName.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).indexOf(
                searchTerm.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`R.style.searchTextHighlight`:

```
<style name="searchTextHiglight">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_accent_2</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

P.S. Ну и соответственно при поиске передавать `searchTerm` в адаптер + `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Thank!!!! Working !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)